# IOS In-App Purchase Auto-Renewal Subscription

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am developing IOS App which is free to download and for internal additional monthly services added concept  In-App Purchase Auto-Renewal Subscription but during implementation & testing I am facing so many issue, I am representing cases here, I dont know my approach is correct or not

Case 1:
From one device using one apple id, Can I subscribe the services for two different app users, If yes than It will charge two times every month? and If I want unsubscribe the services for one user so from manage can i control ?

Case 2:
I have two IOS devices with two different apple id from first device I register the app and subscribe the services for the app after 2 month my first device create problem so on second device I downloaded the app and singin, so my current month subscribtion would be valid or invalid, If valid so next renewal happen from first device apple id or secod device apple id, If invalid it means user can't change his phone during the subscription period.

Case 3:
I have two IOS devices with same apple id from first device I register the app and subscribe the services for the app after 2 month my first device create problem so on second device I downloaded the app and singin, so my current month subscribtion would be valid or invalid?

How can I test all above cases ??

Comment: The subscription is linked to the Apple ID, so in case 1 only a single subscription would be billed. You need to have a "restore purchases" button to enable a user to activate their subscription on another device. This covers case 3 and should also cover case 2 - the user should sign in with the already subscribed Apple ID when they restore purchase on the second device

Answer (score 0):

I think something about my question can anybody verify this:
The Simple Flow:
1. Login in app using User1 (user1@abc.com).
2. Buy/Purchase Subscription using Apple-ID (user1@abc.com).
3. On Successful  Purchase store Transaction Receipt Store on two location one in local phone and second Back-End Server Database, After that on server user flag as Paid User.
4. On Back-End Server cronjob will run and check any subscription is expired, If yes then check will apple renewal is done or not, If renewal done than user flag remain Paid otherwise downgrade to Free User.
5. Now on everylogin we will check local phone receipt, store server receipt and login user, everything match user continue as paid user, If user change his phone so local phone receipt not found than he has to use option Purchase Restore.

Case 1: We can restric the user to use one apple id for on app user purchase

1. On same phone I login with other user (user2@abc.com) and trying to buy services with same apple id. 
    1.1 On same phone if we found previous transaction receipt with user1 so we will not allow user2 to purchase with same apple id and will ask to use another apple id.
    1.2 On same phone user remove the app and install again than all local receipt missed than we have to check transaction with back-end server and found this transaction with user1 so we will not allow user2 to purchase with same apple id and will ask to use another apple id.


Case 2: 
2.1 If user change the phone with different apple id, still user1 consider as subscribed user because auto-renewal continue with previous apple id and our server verify in background.
2.2 If user off the auto-renewal from first apple id than our back-end server consider as free user than user has to do new purchasing from new apple id on second phone.

Case 3: 
If user having multiple phone with same apple id, he can subscribe the service on only one phone with one app user, that user can login on any of the phone consider as subscribed user.

Comment: Hi Ritesh. Did you find your this flow correct? I'm in the same boat as you were.